# Python :: nested JSON result in Spotify

Tags: python, json, data-structures, spotipy

I'm having a really hard time to get a track id in `Spotify` `search endpoint`.

It is deeply nested.

So, if I do this:

```
 results = sp.search(q='artist:' + 'Nirvava + ' track:' + 'Milk it', type='track')
 pprint.pprint(results)
```

I am able to get:

```
{u'tracks': {u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=artist%3ANirvana+track%3AMilk+it&type=track&offset=0&limit=10',
             u'items': [{u'album': {u'album_type': u'album',
                                    u'artists': [{u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh'},
                                                  u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh',
                                                  u'id': u'6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh',
                                                  u'name': u'Nirvana',
                                                  u'type': u'artist',
                                                  u'uri': u'spotify:artist:6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh'}],
                                    u'available_markets': [u'CA',
                                                           u'MX',
                                                           u'US'],
                                    u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/album/7wOOA7l306K8HfBKfPoafr'},
                                    u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7wOOA7l306K8HfBKfPoafr',
                                    u'id': u'7wOOA7l306K8HfBKfPoafr',
                                    u'images': [{u'height': 640,
                                                 u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/3dd2699f0fcf661c35d45745313b64e50f63f91f',
                                                 u'width': 640},
                                                {u'height': 300,
                                                 u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/a6c604a82d274e4728a8660603ef31ea35e9e1bd',
                                                 u'width': 300},
                                                {u'height': 64,
                                                 u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/f52728b0ecf5b6bfc998dfd0f6e5b6b5cdfe73f1',
                                                 u'width': 64}],
                                    u'name': u'In Utero - 20th Anniversary Remaster',
                                    u'type': u'album',
                                    u'uri': u'spotify:album:7wOOA7l306K8HfBKfPoafr'},
                         u'artists': [{u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh'},
                                       u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh',
                                       u'id': u'6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh',
                                       u'name': u'Nirvana',
                                       u'type': u'artist',
                                       u'uri': u'spotify:artist:6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh'}],
                         u'available_markets': [u'CA', u'MX', u'US'],
                         u'disc_number': 1,
                         u'duration_ms': 234746,
                         u'explicit': False,
                         u'external_ids': {u'isrc': u'USGF19960708'},
                         u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/track/4rtZtLpriBscg7zta3TZxp'},
                         u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4rtZtLpriBscg7zta3TZxp',
                         u'id': u'4rtZtLpriBscg7zta3TZxp',
                         u'name': u'Milk It',
                         u'popularity': 43,
                         u'preview_url': None,
                         u'track_number': 8,
                         u'type': u'track',
       ----->            u'uri':u'spotify:track:4rtZtLpriBscg7zta3TZxp'},
```

QUESTION:

now, how do I fetch the last `'uri'` (`u'uri': u'spotify:track:4rtZtLpriBscg7zta3TZxp'`}, under the name 'Milk It'?

Comment: Which of the uri's do you need?

Comment: By the way - could you paste the response again this time import pprint and use pprint.pprint(results) - that would make it a lot easier to dechipher the json structure..

Comment: please refer to edit, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> print results['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
spotify:track:4rtZtLpriBscg7zta3TZxp
```